# I'm looking for possibilities to create a function/class

Tags: jquery, arrays, function

I created a "field'-function to set and get a field's (HTML Input) value.

```
var field = {
    set: function (id, value) {
        if (typeof value === 'undefined') {
            value = '';
        }
        $('#' + id).val(value);
    }
    , get: function (id) {            
        return $('#' + id).val();
    }
}
```

This allows my to set/get an input's value:

```
field.set('myinput','hello');
var v = field.get('myinput');
alert(v);
```

So far so good. Now I'm looking for ways to extend my "function" to set a field's value or attribute (or modify other properties in the future like height, color, visibility etc.)

The syntax should look like this:

```
field.value.set('myinput','hello'); // myinput is the id of an input element
var v = field.value.get('myinput');

field.attr.set('myinput','name','value');
var v = field.attr.get('myinput','name');
```

What possibilities are there to construct such a function/class?

Comment: What are you expecting `var v = field.attr.get('myinput');` to do? You aren't passing an attribute name?

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to achieve, but the short answer is that you already have this functionality: `$`

Comment: @CertainPerformance: Example corrected. var v = field.attr.get('myinput','name');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare additional `value` and `attr` attributes on your `field`, and have each `set` and `get` functions return the appropriate jQuery method:

```js
var field = {
  set: function (id, value) {
    if (typeof value === 'undefined') {
      value = '';
    }
    $('#' + id).val(value);
  }, get: function (id) {            
    return $('#' + id).val();
  },
  value: {
    set: (id, value) => {
      return $('#' + id).val(value);
    },
    get: (id) => {
      return $('#' + id).val();
    },
  },
  attr: {
    set: (id, attrib, value) => {
      return $('#' + id).attr(attrib, value);
    },
    get: (id, attrib) => {
      return $('#' + id).attr(attrib);
    },
  },
};
field.value.set('foo', 'newinput');
field.attr.set('foo', 'name', 'def');
console.log(field.attr.get('foo', 'name'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="foo" name="abc">
```